# IOS app without any UI

Tags: ios, iphone

I have no knowledge of iOS. I need to know if it is possible to create an application without any views. The app should run a background service triggered by the app installation (or boot), and the service will run permanently.

If you click the app icon, nothing should happen.

Thank you

Comment: not possible i guess. but best of luck.

Comment: no it is not possible. If you click app then app must be open and must show some UI!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no such concept as a service type application or functionality in iOS.

The reason is, the [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication) class provides a centralized point of control and coordination for apps running in iOS, which is a part of [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit).

Also, there are restrictions to run the background service in iOS.See the below pic and this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) to know more about background modes for apps.

[image: BackgroundExecution iOS]

**Possible Method:**

This is possible by writing `exit(0);` inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` after the iOS supporting background service is initiated. However, the App-Store will **reject** your app.